# Use NamedTemporaryFile to read from stdout via subprocess on Linux

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, temporary-files

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

fd = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
print(fd)
print(fd.name)
p = subprocess.Popen("date", stdout=fd).communicate()
print(p[0])
fd.close()
```

This returns:

```
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w' at 0x7fc27eb1e810>
/tmp/tmp8kX9C1
None
```

Instead, I would like it to return something like:

```
Tue Jun 23 10:23:15 CEST 2015
```

I tried adding `mode="w"`, as well as `delete=False`, but can't succeed to make it work.

Comment: are you aware of `subprocess.check_output()`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes. In fact, the command I wish to pass to the system is `qstat -xml -r` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26104540/597069). Unfortunately, it seems to behave differently than `date`.

Comment: If you need output of `qstat`; you should ask about `qstat`. It seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Why do you need `NamedTemporaryFile` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `stdout=PIPE`; `p[0]` will always be `None` in your code.

To get output of a command as a string, you could use `check_output()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

result = check_output("date")
```

[`check_output()` uses `stdout=PIPE` and `.communicate()` internally](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l544).

To read output from a file, you should call `.read()` on the file object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as file:
    subprocess.check_call("date", stdout=file)
    file.seek(0) # sync. with disk
    result = file.read()
```